# Image upload to codeigniter error using crud

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey guys Im getting an error Undefined variable see pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1YWV.jpg

What i want to do is upload an image and then send it the url to database.
here is my

profile controller:

```
<?php
    class Profile extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('url', 'html', 'form'));
            $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('user_model');


        }

        function index()
        {
            $details = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('uid'));
            $data['uname'] = $details[0]->firstname . " " . $details[0]->lastname;
            $data['uemail'] = $details[0]->email;
            $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);

        }

        function delete()
        {
            $this->user_model->delete_row($this->session->userdata('uid'));
            redirect('Site/index');

        }

        function update()
        {

            $this->user_model->update($this->input->post("name"), $this->session->userdata('uid'));
            $this->user_model->update($this->input->post("email"), $this->session->userdata('uid'));
            redirect('profile/index');

        }


        public function index1()
        {
            $this->load->view('profile_view', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function do_upload()
        {
            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/img';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('profile_view', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data(), $this->session->userdata('uid'));

                $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
            }
        }
    `}
```

here is my profile view:

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/mystyle.css'); ?>" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url('assets/css/mystyle.css');?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/mystyle.css" type="text/css">
    <?php
    $autoload['helper'] = array('css_js');?>

</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="mascot">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/monstercode.png" alt="Green Monster Mascot" style="width:160px;height:32px;"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url('')?>">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Site/sites')?>">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Site/developers')?>">Developers</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Site/employers')?>">Employers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                <?php if ($this->session->userdata('login')){ ?>

                    <li class="right nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><p class="navbar-text">Hello <?php echo $this->session->userdata('uname'); ?></p></li>
                    <li class="right nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/logout">Log Out</a></li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/signup">Signup</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <div class="well">
                <p>User Picture <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('profile/do_upload'); ?>
            <?php echo form_upload('userfile'); ?><br />
            <?php echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');?>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            <div class="well">
                <p>User Info<br/> Name: <?php echo $uname; ?><br/> Email: <?php echo $uemail; ?> <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">


            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h4>Profile Summary</h4>
                        <hr/>
                        <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('profile/update');?>">
                            <p>Name: <input type="text" name='name'value="<?php echo $uname; ?>"></p>
                            <p>Email:  <input type="text" name='email' value="<?php echo $uemail; ?>"></p>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
                        </form>
                        <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('profile/delete');?>">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                        <p>...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <p>lorem ipsum dolum</p>
                        <p>lorem ipsum dolum</p>
                        <p>lorem ipsum dolum</p>
                        <p>...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <h3>More User Info</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <div class="well">
                <p>Job Offers <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                <p>Job Offers <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know whats wrong with my code. Thanks.

Update Model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class user_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_user($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
       /* Select * from users where email = $_Post['email'] and password = $_post['password'] */
        return $query->result();
    }

    // get user
    function get_user_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        //select id from users where id = $_Post['id']
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query->result();
    }

    // insert
    function insert_user($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
    }


    //delete row
    function delete_row($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('user');
    }

    function update($uemail,  $id) {


            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->set('email', $uemail);
            $this->db->update('user');

    }
    function add_image($uimage, $id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->set('image', $uimage);
        $this->db->update('user');
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also put bellow user information in `do_upload` method :

```
$details = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('uid'));
$data['uname'] = $details[0]->firstname . " " . $details[0]->lastname;
$data['uemail'] = $details[0]->email;
```

Like bellow `do_upload` method :

```
$details = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('uid'));
$data['uname'] = $details[0]->firstname . " " . $details[0]->lastname;
$data['uemail'] = $details[0]->email;
$data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
$data['uid'] = $this->session->userdata('uid')

$this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
```

So, now `do_upload()` method is :

```
public function do_upload() {
    $config['upload_path']          = './assets/img';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    $details = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('uid'));
    $data['uname'] = $details[0]->firstname . " " . $details[0]->lastname;
    $data['uemail'] = $details[0]->email;

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }
    else
    {       
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
        $images_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
        //update user photo intro database
        $this->user_model->add_image($images_name, $this->session->userdata('uid'));

        $data['upload_data'] = $upload_data;
        $data['uid'] = $this->session->userdata('uid')
        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Razib, Thank you for completing my do_upload method but I'm still getting the errors from profile_view.php. please check image for errors
http://imgur.com/oJMbrYo

Comment: when you press submit button for upload image in this time your browser URL like `http://localhost/ASL/profile/do_upload`. right?

Comment: i have edited my answer in `do_upload()` method. you can copy & paste. Let me know

Comment: I the new code took away the error, but for some reason its not uploading to the folder. Im going recheck it again but if you see something what might prevent the image uploading to my assets/img folder please let me know, thank you.

Comment: ok i got it!!! its was the image folder i had wrong!! Thanks so much man!!!

Comment: Hey quick question.. How can i add image url path to database. I updated with my model. it would be great if you can help me. thanks again.

Comment: `$upload_data = $this->upload->data(); $images_name = $upload_data['file_name']` now you can use `$images_name` for store images name in database

Comment: in `do_upload` method `else
 {  
  $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
  $images_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
  
  $data['upload_data'] = $upload_data;
  $data['uid'] = $this->session->userdata('uid')
  $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
 }`

Comment: Hi sorry to bother what exactly i do the with $image_name??

Comment: you can just save images name intro database. In the `$images_name` variable have image name after images upload.

Comment: sorry I'm very new to this could i get the code for it please?

Comment: No its not updating the database with the picture url

Comment: it was the image folder again , lol. Hey man thanks so much i could not do this without you. if there is anything i can do to give you the most credit i will but for now my because I'm new here on stackoverflow they have to review my votes. let me know, thanks so much!!!!!!!!! Happy Holidays.

Comment: How does accepting an answer work >> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work